# How to properly regex match the following string in python?

Tags: python, regex

I have the following string:

1- Baby Carrots (4Kids) (3 DOLLARS) [EXTRA 0 COUNT]; [REQUIRED 5 COUNT]

I am trying to get the following groups:

```
Item - 1
Food - Baby Carrots (4Kids) (3 DOLLARS)
Cost - 3
Extra - 0
required - 5
```

The following is my current match string that is not picking up anything:

```
'(?P<item>.+?)\-(?P<food>.*)\[.*?(?P<extra>\d+(\.\d+)?).*\].*\[.*?(?P<required>\d+(\.\d+)?).*\]'
```

What is wrong with my attempt?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this regex mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean)

Comment: problem is '.+?' would consume complete string.

Comment: You are very close. Where do you attempt to capture the cost? I can't see it in your regex. That is, running your regex I get everything fine except the cost string is merged in with the food string.

Comment: You just edited the name to include (3 DOLLARS). So you want (3 DOLLARS) as part of the food name *and* you want the 3 separately--and redundantly--captured as the cost?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your original regex:

```
(?P<item>.+?)\-(?P<food>.*)\[.*?(?P<extra>\d+(\.\d+)?).*\].*\[.*?(?P<required>\d+(\.\d+)?).*\]
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/ioDNxiP_1NCdlHQ_)

Your problems are mostly due to the fact that you are searching for *any* character, instead of specific ones (digits and static strings). For example: Why do you use

```
(?P<item>.+?)
```

if it's only going to be numbers? Change it to

```
(?P<item>[0-9]+?)
```

and the ['+?':reluctant operator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10764399) is not necessary in this case, since you always want the entire number. That is, the next portion of the match will not be in the *middle* of that number.

In addition, this should be anchored to [line (input) start](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22759143/578411):

```
^(?P<item>[0-9]+?)
```

You don't need to [escape](https://stackoverflow.com/q/399078) the dash (although it doesn't hurt).

```
^(?P<item>[0-9]+?)-
```

Your food group (heh) is the most complicated part

```
(?P<food>.*)
```

It doesn't just contain *any* character. Based on your demo input, it only has letters, spaces, numbers, and parens. So search just for them:

```
(?P<food>[\w0-9 ()]+)
```

Here's what we have so far:

```
^(?P<item>[0-9]+?)- (?P<food>[\w0-9 ()]+)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/n7_fLeBHoT4n0gIr)

You'll see that this also matches the cost part (which is completely missing from your regex...I assume that's just an oversight).

So add the cost, which is

- `(`
- a number
- `[space]DOLLARS)`

But only [capture](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21880127) the number:

```
^(?P<item>[0-9]+?)- (?P<food>[\w0-9 ()]+) \((?P<cost>[0-9]+) DOLLARS\)
```

The rest of your regex works fine, actually, and it can be added to the end as is:

```
\[.*?(?P<extra>\d+(\.\d+)?).*\].*\[.*?(?P<required>\d+(\.\d+)?).*\]
```

I'd recommend, however, changing the `.*?` to `EXTRA[space]` if indeed that text is always found there (and again, no need for reluctance in this case). Same with `[space]COUNT`, `;` and `REQUIRED[space]`. The more you narrow things down, the easier your regex will be to debug--assuming your input is indeed that restricted.

Here's the final version (with an end-of-line anchor as well):

```
^(?P<item>[0-9]+?)- (?P<food>[\w0-9 ()]+) \((?P<cost>[0-9]+) DOLLARS\) \[EXTRA (?P<extra>\d+(\.\d+)?) COUNT\]; \[REQUIRED (?P<required>\d+(\.\d+)?) COUNT\]$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/qesgjbWCo6IWtqUF)

---

Before analyzing your regex, this is what I came up with:

```
(?P<item>[0-9]+)- (?P<food>[\w ()]+) \((?P<cost>[0-9]+) DOLLARS\) \[EXTRA (?P<extra>[0-9]+) COUNT\]; \[REQUIRED (?P<required>[0-9]+) COUNT\]
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/izh_m3gc--VPnSna)

---

All these links came from the [Stack Overflow Regular Expressions FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/2736496).

Answer (score 0):

like this :

```
(?P<item>.+?)\-\s(?P<food>.*?\)).*?\((?P<cost>\d)\s\w+\)\s\[.*?(?P<extra>\d+(\.\d+)?).*\].*\[.*?(?P<required>\d+(\.\d+)?).*\]
```

demo here : http://regex101.com/r/qD1rL9

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above, you are missing a *capture* for cost, you also need to make the `food` capture *non-greedy* and include the closing paren. My version:

```
(?P<Item>\d)-\s*(?P<Food>.*?\))\s*\((?P<Cost>\d*).*EXTRA\s*(?P<Extra>\d*).*REQUIRED\s*(?P<Required>\d*)

{'Food': 'Baby Carrots (4Kids)', 'Item': '1', 'Required': '5', 'Extra': '0', 'Cost': '3'}
```

Seems a bit faster using http://www.pythonregex.com/