# Need ideas for a search and replace

Tags: regex, replace, sed

i am frustrated while trying to solve a problem. Perhaps anyone has a idea and can help me.

I have to search for a special pattern and then cut it off.

Input Data are many million rows like this:

> |FIL=827|KAS=1|BON=4189|IND=1|BED=2610|LAD=8011|DAT=20140317|UHR=090500|TYP=LOGPLU|CEURO=1|BWWS=1|BDISP=1|BDRUCK=1|BSTART=1|BAH=1|BARTSCAN=1|BREPEAT=1|ZT0=TI_NUMMER|ZW0=2400850000000|ZA0=MF
>   Sonnenblumen
>   2,5kg|ZT1=TI_MENGE|ZW1=1|ZT2=TI_WGR|ZW2=9|ZT3=TI_MWST|ZW3=1|ZT4=TI_PARA|ZW4=0|ZT5=TI_PARA2|ZW5=0|ZT6=TI_EPREIS|ZW6=7.99|ZT7=TI_GPREIS|ZW7=7.99|ZT8=TI_BASISDETAIL|ZW8=30|106

If there is a pattern like `"ZW0=240"` this part has to be shortend to `"ZW0=2400850"`

Any Ideas ?

Comment: what exactly do you want?

Comment: `"ZW0=240" this part has to be shortend to "ZW0=2400850"`, isnt it already shortened? :\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get this part out of the entire input string and *then* change this one value, first extract it with

```
\b(ZW0=[0-9]+)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/1mweM3a4I_TlPTiz). The [word boundary (`\b`)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6664167) is important to prevent something like `ABCXYZW0=123048734` from being incorrectly matched. It could alternatively be an [escaped](https://stackoverflow.com/q/399078) or-pipe: (`\|`).

Once this value is extracted, you can eliminate "all but one on the trailing zeros" with the following replacement:

- Find what: `(.*?[0-9]+?0)0+$`
- Replace with: `$1`
- Try it: http://regex101.com/r/iE1nM4

Here's the find-what term:

```
^(.*?[0-9]+?0)0+$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/bdFkQJL_EavTKD58)

The [end-of-line anchor (`$`)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22759143/578411) is critical here. Without it, it would result instead in `ZW0=240`. And without the [reluctant quantifier (`?`)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10764399) before the numbers (`.*?`), you would end up with `ZW0=240085000000`. This is because it would only eliminate the *one* remaining zero.

Alternatively, if you want to change this value, but leave the entire input string intact, use this:

- Find what: `^(.*?)\|(ZW0=[0-9]+?0)0+(\|.*)$`
- Replace with: `$1$2$3`
- Try it: http://regex101.com/r/bQ3tT6

---

Please consider bookmarking the [Stack Overflow Regular Expressions FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/2736496) for future reference. The links in this answer come from it. In particular, the section at the bottom contains a list of online testers, where you can try things out yourself.

Comment: Wow, 

you guys are awesome and fast. Your input works great, but perhaps i wasn't precise enough.

I need to find the string starting "ZW0=240xxxxxxxx" - this number is always 13 digits.
If it matches this criteria i need a replace to the first 6 digits.

in this case : "ZW0=240085" - all other case shouldn't be touched.

is this possible ?

Comment: Find what: `(240?[0-9]{3})[0-9]+$`, replace with `$1`. Best of luck!