# Regular expression to find all backslashes

Tags: regex, netbeans

I need to find all backslashes in rows that start with "require_once" like these:

```
require_once $doc_root . "\inc\common.php";
require_once $doc_root . "\inc\admin_login.php";
require_once $doc_root . "\inc\usps_functions.php";
require_once $doc_root . '\lib\PDFMerger\PDFMerger.php';
```

I tried to use this one:

http://regex101.com/r/fP5fT5/1

Comment: What do you want to do with it? What's the expected result/output?

Comment: If you want to match the entire line, you can just use something like `^require_once \$doc_root \. (['"])\\([^"']+)\1;$`. [See demo](http://regex101.com/r/fP5fT5/2). (The `x` modifier isn't required.)

Comment: I want to paste the reg expression in the Netbeans search function so it will find all backslashes and replace them with forwardslashles.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
^require_once.+[\\]+.*;$
```

For more information visit: http://regexpal.com/

Comment: If the goal is to capture the path, starting with the first `/`, then this regex is [incorrect](https://www.debuggex.com/r/hkfzVUqgfw16Ip-d) (I've added a group to highlight the problem). With the [greedy](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10764399) `.+`, it only captures the text following the *last* slash. It needs to be changed to reluctant: [`^require_once.+?[\\]+.*;$`](https://www.debuggex.com/r/66OEmoXvQ59OhBK4). (And actually, if the goal is to capture, it *should* contain those capture groups.)

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
(?m)(?:^require_once|(?<!^)\G)[^\\]*?\K\\
```

See [demo on regex 101](http://regex101.com/r/gY7rO4/39).

Comment: FYI Added demo, let me know if this works for you. :)