# Confused about Grabbing HTML Tags regex pattern

Tags: java, regex

I was reading [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) examples to try to learn more regex patterns.

The first example [Grabbing HTML Tags](http://www.regular-expressions.info/examples.html) talks about a regex for the opening and closing pair of a specific HTML tag.

```
<TAG\b[^>]*>(.*?)</TAG>
```

I'm a little confused here. Why is `\b[^>]*` added to the above regex pattern, where the same thing can be achieved by using the below regex pattern:

```
<TAG>(.*?)</TAG>
```

Why is this extra regex pattern used? Will it help in any performance?

Comment: This link may be relevant (or at least interesting): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: I got it. I was just looking for some examples that explain about the use of this extra regex pattern. Thanks to all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- That's in order to match things like `<a href=...> stuff </a>`, as opposed to a simple `<b> stuff </b>` where your option would work.
- The `\b` boundary is needed in order to avoid matching things like `<attribute ...> stuff </a>`
- The lazy quantifier `.*?` between the opening and closing tags is needed, as opposed to `[^<]*`, because between the opening and closing tags you might have another tag (for instance `<b>`)

Comment: Thanks I got it. I literally forget about this type of uses.

Comment: Thanks for description. I was just looking for the uses of this extra pattern. That's clear to me.

Answer (score 0):

Because without the word boundary, it matches anything  not only the tags.

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/zN2vG6/1)

You could try the demo. Just play with and without `\b` in the pattern.

```
<TAG\b[^>]*>(.*?)</TAG>
```

**Explanation:**

- `<` Matches `<` symbol.
- `TAG` Tag name
- `\b` Matches between a word character and a non-word character.
- `[^>]*` Matches any chars not of `>` zero or more times.
- `(.*?)` Captures the section within the opening and closing tag.`?` after the `*` does an reluctant match.
- `</TAG>` Matches the end tag.

**For example:**

Input:

```
<a href="www.foo.com">link</a>
<ahref="www.foo.com">link</a>
```

Regex:

```
<a[^>]*>(.*?)<\/a>
```

The above regex would match both the links.

Regex:

```
<a\b[^>]*>(.*?)<\/a>
```

But this would match the first one because there is an word boundary exists between `a` and the first `space` character.

Comment: forget to add the proper link.

Comment: @Braj now check that.

Answer (score 0):

Some opening tags have attributes like `<img src="asdf.png">`. The tag does not end until the `>` is reached, so the word boundary and non-`>` characters match the `src="asdf.png"`.

Answer (score 0):

The `\b[^>]*` in

```
<TAG\b[^>]*>(.*?)</TAG>
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/V5rj5bPXjfwXe0P0)

allows there to be text (such as parameters: `width="30"`) and whitespace in the open-tag (as long as it's only a `TAG` and not `TAGX` or some other type--that's what the `\b` [word boundary](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6664167) is for). Syntax and spacing in html is very loosey goosey. It's always safe to allow extra parameters and whitespace, as a single html tag can span many lines.

The latter regex

```
<TAG>(.*?)</TAG>
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/iTNZoXu4ke2VWdZ_)

Only allows the opening tag to be *exactly* `<TAG>` then "some text which may span multiple lines", then `</TAG>`.

The `?` in  `.*?` is [reluctance](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10764399), meaning the *next* close `</TAG>` is the only one that can be matched. Eliminating the `?` changes it to [greedy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10764399), meaning that the *last close `</TAG>` in the search-string* is matched.

---

Be sure to check out the [Stack Overflow Regular Expressions FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/2736496)  :)