# Java regex. Extracting group from a text excluding specific char sequence. (It's working like backward matching)

Tags: java, regex, string

I have read similar questions to solve my problem, but without any solution.
I'm having troubles extracting a group from the following string:

```
    String str = "/a> ref|NP_010829.1| Irc4p [Saccharomyces cerevisiae S288c] &gt;gi|74676333|sp|Q03036.1|IRC4_YEAST  RecName: Full=Uncharacterized protein IRC4;  AltName: Full=Increased recombination centers protein 4 &gt;gi|1165295|gb|AAB64982.1|  Ydr540cp [Saccharomyces cerevisiae]  &gt;gi|51012753|gb|AAT92670.1| YDR540C [Saccharomyces cerevisiae]  &gt;gi|151942499|gb|EDN60855.1| conserved protein [Saccharomyces  cerevisiae YJM789] &gt;gi|190404545|gb|EDV07812.1|  conserved hypothetical protein [Saccharomyces cerevisiae  RM11-1a] &gt;gi|259145774|emb|CAY79038.1| Irc4p [Saccharomyces  cerevisiae EC1118] &gt;gi|285811545|tpg|DAA12369.1| TPA:  Irc4p [Saccharomyces cerevisiae S288c] &gt;gi|323309617|gb|EGA62826.1|  Irc4p [Saccharomyces cerevisiae FostersO] &gt;gi|323338091|gb|EGA79326.1|  Irc4p [Saccharomyces cerevisiae Vin13]  &gt;gi|365766295|gb|EHN07794.1| Irc4p [Saccharomyces cerevisiae  x Saccharomyces kudriavzevii VIN7] &gt;gi|392300658|gb|EIW11749.1|  Irc4p [Saccharomyces cerevisiae CEN.PK113-7D]  &gt;gi|584366859|gb|EWG86852.1| Irc4p [Saccharomyces cerevisiae  R008] &gt;gi|584372222|gb|EWG92158.1| Irc4p [Saccharomyces  cerevisiae P301] &gt;gi|584376691|gb|EWG96547.1| Irc4p  [Saccharomyces cerevisiae R103] &gt;gi|584477456|gb|EWH19199.1|  Irc4p [Saccharomyces cerevisiae P283]";
```

What I want to do is to parse the string capturing a group with any characters until first occurrence of `"&gt;"`, resulting in the following string:

```
result = "/a> ref|NP_010829.1| Irc4p [Saccharomyces cerevisiae S288c]";
```

I have tried the following regex pattern using the `replaceAll(regex, replacement)` method:

```
str = str.replaceAll("^(.+)&gt;.+", "$1");
```

Where **`"^(.+)&gt;.+"` should match any character until first occurrence of `"&gt;"`, but the group `"^(.+)"` follows until the last occurrence of `"&gt;"`**

Then the result is:

```
from: "/a> ref|NP_010829.1| Irc4p [Saccharomyces cerevisiae S288c] &gt;gi|74676333|sp|Q03036.1|IRC4_YEAST  RecName: Full=Uncharacterized protein IRC4;  AltName: Full=Increased recombination centers protein 4 &gt;gi|1165295|gb|AAB64982.1|  Ydr540cp [Saccharomyces cerevisiae]  &gt;gi|51012753|gb|AAT92670.1| YDR540C [Saccharomyces cerevisiae]  &gt;gi|151942499|gb|EDN60855.1| conserved protein [Saccharomyces  cerevisiae YJM789] &gt;gi|190404545|gb|EDV07812.1|  conserved hypothetical protein [Saccharomyces cerevisiae  RM11-1a] &gt;gi|259145774|emb|CAY79038.1| Irc4p [Saccharomyces  cerevisiae EC1118] &gt;gi|285811545|tpg|DAA12369.1| TPA:  Irc4p [Saccharomyces cerevisiae S288c] &gt;gi|323309617|gb|EGA62826.1|  Irc4p [Saccharomyces cerevisiae FostersO] &gt;gi|323338091|gb|EGA79326.1|  Irc4p [Saccharomyces cerevisiae Vin13]  &gt;gi|365766295|gb|EHN07794.1| Irc4p [Saccharomyces cerevisiae  x Saccharomyces kudriavzevii VIN7] &gt;gi|392300658|gb|EIW11749.1|  Irc4p [Saccharomyces cerevisiae CEN.PK113-7D]  &gt;gi|584366859|gb|EWG86852.1| Irc4p [Saccharomyces cerevisiae  R008] &gt;gi|584372222|gb|EWG92158.1| Irc4p [Saccharomyces  cerevisiae P301] &gt;gi|584376691|gb|EWG96547.1| Irc4p  [Saccharomyces cerevisiae R103] &gt;gi|584477456|gb|EWH19199.1|  Irc4p [Saccharomyces cerevisiae P283]";
to: "/a> ref|NP_010829.1| Irc4p [Saccharomyces cerevisiae S288c] &gt;gi|74676333|sp|Q03036.1|IRC4_YEAST  RecName: Full=Uncharacterized protein IRC4;  AltName: Full=Increased recombination centers protein 4 &gt;gi|1165295|gb|AAB64982.1|  Ydr540cp [Saccharomyces cerevisiae]  &gt;gi|51012753|gb|AAT92670.1| YDR540C [Saccharomyces cerevisiae]  &gt;gi|151942499|gb|EDN60855.1| conserved protein [Saccharomyces  cerevisiae YJM789] &gt;gi|190404545|gb|EDV07812.1|  conserved hypothetical protein [Saccharomyces cerevisiae  RM11-1a] &gt;gi|259145774|emb|CAY79038.1| Irc4p [Saccharomyces  cerevisiae EC1118] &gt;gi|285811545|tpg|DAA12369.1| TPA:  Irc4p [Saccharomyces cerevisiae S288c] &gt;gi|323309617|gb|EGA62826.1|  Irc4p [Saccharomyces cerevisiae FostersO] &gt;gi|323338091|gb|EGA79326.1|  Irc4p [Saccharomyces cerevisiae Vin13]  &gt;gi|365766295|gb|EHN07794.1| Irc4p [Saccharomyces cerevisiae  x Saccharomyces kudriavzevii VIN7] &gt;gi|392300658|gb|EIW11749.1|  Irc4p [Saccharomyces cerevisiae CEN.PK113-7D]  &gt;gi|584366859|gb|EWG86852.1| Irc4p [Saccharomyces cerevisiae  R008] &gt;gi|584372222|gb|EWG92158.1| Irc4p [Saccharomyces  cerevisiae P301] &gt;gi|584376691|gb|EWG96547.1| Irc4p  [Saccharomyces cerevisiae R103]";
```

To achieve my result is like doing a loop checking if `str.contains("&gt;")` and then using the `str.replaceAll("^(.+)&gt;.+", "$1");` to eliminate any char sequence **like a backwarding matching**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the `.+` in your regex

```
^(.+)&gt;.+
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/uROLZtsp_5g3HunJ)

is [greedy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10764399), meaning (as you have discovered), that it *greedily* consumes all instances of `&gt;` except the last. Changing this to [reluctant](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10764399)

```
^(.+?)&gt;.+
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/ldijgFKtvOPyGlBE)

is what you want: it *reluctantly* captures only up through the *first* `&gt;`

- Elements that are **greedy** capture as *much as possible*, as long as the overall regex can still match.
- Elements that are **reluctant** capture as *little as possible*, as long as the overall regex can still match.

---

Please consider bookmarking the [Stack Overflow Regular Expressions FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/2736496) for future reference.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. This FAQ will clarify me a lot for future references.

Answer (score 3):

You need to make the pattern to does a non-greedy match by adding `?` quatifier after `+`,

```
^(.+?)&gt;.*$
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/jI6gE8/3)

Your Java code would be,

```
str = str.replaceAll("^(.+?)&gt;.*$", "$1");
```

Then replace the whole string with the first captured group.

Answer (score 1):

```
str = str.replaceAll("^(.+?)&gt;.+", "$1");
```

Non-greedy!

Alternatively, you could use

```
 str = str.replaceAll("&gt;.*", "");
```

which should leave you with all characters up to the first `&gt;`.

Also

```
String[] parts = str.split( "&lt;", 2 );
```

would have been an option, as you don't want to chnge `str`.

Comment: Hi @laune, thanks for your feedback. I'll use this alternative way. I'm owing some reply in drools community about something that I wanted to do.

Answer (score 1):

`+` quantifier is greedy so it will try to find maximal possible match like `.+b` will match

```
abababcd
^^^^^^
```

instead of

```
abababcd
^^
```

If you want to make this quantifier find minimal possible match make it reluctant by adding `?` after it.

This time `.+?b` would match

```
abababcd
^^
```

So change your regex to `^(.+?)&gt;.+`.

---

You can also use some simpler mechanism instead of regex. I mean `substring` and `indexOf` which can look like

```
//                     |substring from 0
//                     |      |till index of first "&gt;"
result = str.substring(0, str.indexOf("&gt;"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that `.*` is greedy and should be made *reluctant* by adding a `?`, but there is an even simpler solution:

```
str = str.replaceAll("&gt;.*", "");
```

Just match what you *don't* want and delete it (by replacing it with nothing).