# What means + and * in regex expession

Tags: regex

I have this regex expression `^[?+ A-zA-Z0-9]*$`, but it's not clear what `+` and `*` means. I searched on the Internet, but I did not find a clear explanation. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Wouldn't google be quicker - https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=regex+operators

Comment: see here, you will get your answer , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10763820/difference-between-and-regex?answertab=votes#tab-top

Answer (score 2):

They are quantifiers for repeating the patterns before them.

http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html