# Regex find parameterized property

Tags: regex, vb.net

I am trying to build a regex to identify the parameterized property of VB.

Example code of a parameterized property i want to match

```
Public ReadOnly Property Test(v as String) As Integer
Public ReadOnly Property Test(ByVal v as String) As ReadOnlyCollection(Of Guid)
```

Example code of a property i want to avoid

```
Public ReadOnly Property Test() As Integer         
Public ReadOnly Property Test() As ReadOnlyCollection(Of Guid)
```

Basically if there are any parameters passed to the property i want it to match, but there are other cases with other parenthesis in the same line as the type of the property that might not have parameters. 
The pattern i see is

> property [0 or more empty space] [next word] [0 or more empty space] ( [0 or more empty space] Target characters OR Ignore WhiteSpace [0 or more empty space] )

This is what i have so far

```
Property?\s+(\w+)\s*(\([^()]*\))
```

Sadly it does not ignore cases with the empty parenthesis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `[^()]*` to `[^()]+`. `+` makes the previous selector match 1 or more times, whilst `*` makes it match 0 or more times. You can read more here: [Difference between * and + regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10763820/difference-between-and-regex)

[regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/FpCwKX/1)

Here's what your regex should end up as:

```
Property?\s+(\w+)\s*(\([^()]+\))
```

Comment: So close but yet so far! Thanks.