# How to groups() in regex with whitespace

Tags: python, regex

I have a regex that i'm trying to match the phone number. However, 1 of the scenario of phone numbers have blanks/whites paces in the front and it's causing groups() error because of NoneType

How do I avoid this?

```
s = ' 1234567890'

pattern = re.compile(r'''^(?:\s*\(?)(\d{3})\)*[-\. ]*(\d{3})[-. ]?(\d{4})\s+$''',re.VERBOSE)
match = pattern.match(s)

match.groups()
```

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'groups'

Comment: What about `pattern.match(s.strip())`?

Comment: The string does not match. What are the requirements? Why `\s+` at the end? It requires 1+ whitespaces, but your input has no whitespace at the end. Use `\s*`

Comment: I'd want to break the phone number into groups.... s.strip() doesn't work

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew OMG That works....I didn't even realize the typo. Regex is tricky!

Comment: You may read about the difference at the [linked post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10763820/difference-between-and-regex).