# Regex - Alternate between letters and numbers

Tags: regex

I am wondering how to build a regex that would match forever "D1B2C4Q3" but not "DDA1Q3" nor "D$1A2B".

That is a number must always follow a letter and vice versa. I've been working on this for a while and my current expression `^([A-Z0-9])(?!)+$` clearly does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
^([A-Z][0-9])+$
```

By combining the letters and digits into a single character class, the expression matches either in any order. You need to seperate the classes sequentially within a group.

Comment: On the same theme...

`^(([A-Z][0-9]|[0-9][A-Z])+)$`

Will also match a sequence beginning with a letter and alternating - not one of your test cases but implied as valid by the question.

Comment: Your comment was the right solution. I should provided more details, but thank you very much!

Comment: This answer doesn't match things like `3C4D5E`, [see the demo](https://regex101.com/r/pjjraw/1).

Comment: Additionally, if you want to include sequences with odd numbers of characters, you could use:
`^((\d([A-Z]\d)*[A-Z]?)|([A-Z](\d[A-Z])*\d?))$`

Answer (score 1):

I might actually use a simple regex pattern with a negative lookahead to prevent duplicate letters/numbers from occurring:

```
^(?!.*(?:[A-Z]{2,}|[0-9]{2,}))[A-Z0-9]+$
```

### Demo

The reason I chose this approach, rather than a non lookaround one, is that we don't know a priori whether the input would start or end with a number or letter.  There are actually four possible combinations of start/end, and this could make for a messy pattern.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing maybe,

```
^(?!.*\d{2}|.*[A-Z]{2})[A-Z0-9]+$
```

might work OK, or maybe not.

#### [Demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/afftdf/1/)

A better approach would be:

```
^(?:[A-Z]\d|\d[A-Z])+$
```

#### [Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/tdHazg/1/)

Or

```
^(?:[A-Z]\d|\d[A-Z])*$
```

Or

```
^(?:[A-Z]\d|\d[A-Z]){1,}$
```

which would depend if you'd like to have an empty string valid or not.

Answer (score 0):

Another idea that will match `A`, `A1`, `1A`, `A1A`, ...

```
^\b\d?(?:[A-Z]\d)*[A-Z]?$
```

[See this demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/UeNXP0/1/)

- `\b` the [word boundary](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) at `^` [start](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) requires at least one char (**remove**, if empty string valid)
- `\d?` followed by an [optional](https://www.regular-expressions.info/optional.html) [digit](https://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html)
- `(?:[A-Z]\d)*` followed by [any amount](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10763820/difference-between-and-regex/10764399#10764399) of [(?:](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html#noncap) upper alpha followed by digit `)`
- `[A-Z]?$` ending in an optional upper alpha

If you want to accept **lower alphas** as well, use [`i` flag](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_i.asp).