# Find the words from the file whose first letter is capitalized

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

I need to write a script that finds all of the capitalized words (not words in all caps, just the initial letter) in a text file and presents them in alphabetical order.

I tried to use a regex like this:

```
re.findall(r'\b[A-Z][a-z]*\b', line)
```

but my function returns this output:

```
Enter the file name: bzip2.txt
['A', 'All', 'Altered', 'C', 'If', 'Julian', 'July', 'R', 'Redistribution', 'Redistributions', 'Seward', 'The', 'This']
```

How can I remove all the single-letter words (ex: A, C, and R)?

Comment: how about removing words with len==1?

Comment: You could iterate over the list and remove words that are length 1. Or alternatively, keep words that are longer than 1 character.

Comment: Change `*` to `+`.

Answer (score 5):

You can do this within the regex itself, no need to filter the array. Just use `+` instead of `*`:

```
re.findall(r'\b[A-Z][a-z]+\b', line)
```

In RegEx, `*` means to match zero or more times, while `+` means to match one or more times. Hence, your original code matched the lowercase letters zero times, so it was essentially ignored). With the `+`, it will be forced to match at least once. You can learn more about this from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10763820/difference-between-and-regex) and its answers.

Also, credit where credit is due: [blhsing](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6890912/blhsing) also pointed this out in the comments of the original question while I was writing this answer.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski Thanks, I've updated my answer with a short description.

Comment: @blhsing Sorry! I didn't realize you also pointed this out in the comments. I've updated my answer with an acknowledgment.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a regex, split and directly check

- has at least 2 characters
- first letter is a capitalized letter

Then call `sorted()` to get a sorted list

```py
>>> alphabet = set("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ")
>>> sorted(filter(lambda word: len(word) >= 2 and word[0] in alphabet, my_collection))
['All', 'Altered', 'If', 'Julian', 'July', 'Redistribution', 'Redistributions', 'Seward', 'The', 'This']
```