# Python: regex number with different cases

Tags: python, regex

Consider:

```
import re
l='the number is 35.897, please check'
print(re.sub(r"([0-9])\.([0-9])", r"\1 of", l))

i='the number is 35+897, please check'
print(re.sub(r"([0-9])\+([0-9])", r"\1 plus", i))

j='the number is 35、897, please check'
print(re.sub(r"([0-9])\、([0-9])", r"\1 and \2", j))

k='the number is 35-897, please check'
print(re.sub(r"([0-9])\-([0-9])", r"\1 of \2", k))
```

Output (annotated):

```
the number is 35 of97, please check     # I want '35 of' instead
the number is 35 plus97, please check   # I want '35 plus' instead
the number is 35 and 897, please check  # Correct
the number is 35 of 897, please check   # Correct
```

I do not know why when I used `.` and `+` in my regex, the result is not what I expected. I don't want the number after . and +, I thought \2 means 897. How can I fix it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between \* and + regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10763820/difference-between-and-regex)

Comment: @InSync OP is not using `*`, they have no quantifier at all, which is the problem. If they had used `*`, the code would have worked. So I don't think that's an appropriate dupe.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. Vote retracted.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that in the second capture group, you are only matching one digit, so only the first digit (`8`) gets captured in group 2, and the `97` is not replaced at all. Change the second capture group to match multiple digits i.e.

```
r"([0-9])\.([0-9]+)"
```

In your code:

```
import re
l='the number is 35.897, please check'
print(re.sub(r"([0-9])\.([0-9]+)", r"\1 of", l))

i='the number is 35+897, please check'
print(re.sub(r"([0-9])\+([0-9]+)", r"\1 plus", i))

j='the number is 35、897, please check'
print(re.sub(r"([0-9])\、([0-9]+)", r"\1 and \2", j))

k='the number is 35-897, please check'
print(re.sub(r"([0-9])\-([0-9]+)", r"\1 of \2", k))
```

Output:

```
the number is 35 of, please check
the number is 35 plus, please check
the number is 35 and 897, please check
the number is 35 of 897, please check
```

Note you could also potentially change the first capture group to also match multiple digits, but that will not affect the results for the code you have in your question.